# How can I test this Interesting series limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

can someone help me to prove this please

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x^{n^{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$

I try to use the expansion of 1/sqrt(1-x) but I don't get anything, thanks for your attention

Comment: My guess, which might lead nowhere, is that your are supposed to convert it into a Reimann sum, and then construct and evaluate the corresponding integration problem.

Comment: Looks like you should compare it to a gaussian function

Comment: Denoting the theta function $\theta(s)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi s}$ and using the functional equation $\theta(s)=\frac{\theta(\frac{1}{s})}{\sqrt s}$(http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/fourier-analysis/theta-zeta.pdf , page 4)
$$\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2\ln\frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt{1-x}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\theta\Big(\frac{\ln\frac{1}{x}}{\pi}\Big)+\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2}\Big(\sqrt\frac{\pi}{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\theta\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln\frac{1}{x}}}\Big)+1\Big)$$

Comment: All the terms of $\theta\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln\frac{1}{x}}}\Big)$ are exponentially small at $x\to1^-$, except for $n=0;\quad \theta\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln\frac{1}{x}}}\Big)\to 1$. The limit follows.